# How to restrict access to local resources with RDS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-terminal-services, rds

I've got a RDS setup on Windows server 2012 and I am trying to stop all access to local resources. I've managed to lock down unc network shares i.e `\\someserver\myshare` and clipboard etc has been disabled. Also, I can't access `\\tsclient\` so thats great.

The only issue I now have is that I can still access my own computer shares via UNC paths i.e `\\mycomputername`.

Is there any way to restrict this? (please bear in mind, I only want to stop this on this one server).

If it helps, I am running XenServer and this server is a VM so I do have a firewall I can access around the VM which is how I am disabling normal shares.

Comment: Can you clarify 'stop all access to local resources'?  Obviously the users will need access to their profiles, program files etc...?

Comment: Sorry what I mean is any files that are on the computer the user is connecting from. I want them to have access to everything on the TS but not be able to move any files off of that machine.

Comment: Ah comprendez, I misunderstood.

Comment: I think the following setting will prevent access to UNC shares:
User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Start Menu and Task Bar>Remove Run menu from Start Menu

Comment: What about windows explorer (Windows Key + E) then typing `\\somecomputer` in the address bar?

Comment: I don't know, what happens when you try this?

Comment: I can still access the network path. I've managed to get around this now though by disabling the service against the ethernet connection. Not sure of the side effects of this but we shall see.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for http://serverfault.com/questions/408992/secure-remote-rdp-worker-prevent-file-transfer?